# Logging errors VBA

Tags: vba, excel, plc

I've been a long time reader of SO but it looks that it's time to ask my first question...

I've been asked to do a datalogging system for an Omron PLC. As client as always the best idea ever, they imposed me to do so, all in VBA. So they can debug it themselves. Good luck with that :)

So my issue is:
I want my application to run without showing any sign of error. 
So you'll tell me : use "Application.DisplayAlerts". Ok.
Then I want to have a history of when an error occurs.
So I use the "On Error" statement and do my things.

But, the lib I'm using now, gives me, only a prompt message, showing an error description and doesn't provide any error code.
So the question is, does anyone knows a solution to save the message contained in this prompt, but not showing it?

Hope it's clear enough,
Thks for you help !

Comment: For me, it seems the lib have handled the error already.  You may need to contact the developer of that lib for better answer.

Comment: Is it a class, if so can you declare the lib `withevents` it may have a `lib_error(errormsg as string)` type event exposed.

Comment: Well...
After contacting their support team. There is some more functions which are not detailed in the manual. One to avoid message from appearing and another giving the last error code. 
Problem solved !

Thanks for you help !